# Desktop Background Is not Showing Up In 21.04 Screenshot

Tags: screenshot, 21.04

> [image]

As you can see here, the background was made invisible on my desktop when I took a screen shot. I am not sure why. This happened after I updated to 21.04.

Comment: Isn't that a Wayland *feature*?